# Where were the Iowa "satellite caucuses" located?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party, primaries, iowa

I've read (somewhat) conflicting report on these, some reproduced in other questions here... For example, Fox News [says](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/satellite-caucuses-aim-to-reach-more-voters)

> In total, there will be 96 locations across the globe on Monday. Thirteen states, plus D.C., will host them. Outside of the U.S., there will be satellite caucuses in Georgia, France, and Scotland.

On the other hand, Radio Iowa [says](https://www.radioiowa.com/2019/12/18/iowa-democratic-party-approves-99-satellite-caucus-locations/):

> Seventy-one of the satellite caucus locations are in Iowa at places like college campuses, senior living facilities and churches and religious centers.

So, is there an official breakdown of these satellite caucuses by in-Iowa and out-of-Iowa and similarly for in-US and outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDP site has a list. See here for details:
https://www.thecaucuses.org/satellite-caucuses

> > caucuses at 87 additional caucus locations around the world — including 60 in-state, 24 out-of-state (across 13 states and D.C) and 3 international locations.

On that page is a list of cities, and a link to the precise locations.

The international ones were Glasgow, Paris, and Tbilisi.